# Spring Recursive Lazy Loading Children Entities

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to retrieve recursively all offices under a Head Office.. However I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying stream through the second generation.

```
public class Office extends AbstractPersistableCustom<Long>{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @Builder.Default
    private List<Office> children = new LinkedList<>();

    // For retrieving children recursively
    public Stream<Office> flattened() {
        return Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(this),
                children.stream().flatMap(Office::flattened));
    }

}
```

RepositoryWrapper

```
 public Office findOfficeHierarchy(final Long id) {
        final Office office = this.repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new OfficeNotFoundException(id));
        office.loadLazyCollections();          
        return office ;
    }
```

In my controller class

```
List<Office> recursive= children.stream().flatMap(Office::flattened).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I really want to avoid using FetchType.EAGER due to large amounts of data.

Any suggestions?